# Its possible to call ndk libraries with root access?

Tags: android, c++, sockets

Hello i want to create a socket in my native code for implement an more fast ping function by using sockets like this:

```
if ( (socketid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");   /* probably not running as superuser */
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,TAG,"socket error: ret %d error: %d",socketid,errno);
        return false;
    }
```

But i realize that this returns an errno of 1 (EPERM or Operation not permited) strangely i set the INTERNET permission and my android device is an emulator x86 (so is rooted), i read in somewhere that this is not possible in a native way but i ask here if any have an solution or for assume that is entirely impossible at moment.